# How to Customize this mixin in JADE

Tags: node.js, pug, mixins

I'm working on a mixin in Jade which creates divs with img tags... here is the mixin code:

```
mixin image(pics)
  each pic in pics
    .row
      .col-md-4
        img.img-responsive(src="#{pic.path}" alt="#{pic.name}")
```

and here is an example when I use the mixin:

```
+image([
    {'name':'anti'    , 'path':'/images/anti.jpg'},
    {'name':'dark'    , 'path':'/images/dark.jpg'},
    {'name':'haik'    , 'path':'/images/haik.jpg'},
    {'name':'james'   , 'path':'/images/james.jpg'},
    {'name':'johanna' , 'path':'/images/johanna.jpg'},
    {'name':'timothy' , 'path':'/images/Timothy.jpg'}
    ])
```

Is it possible to assign all this values to a variable in other file then includes the file and use the mixin? if yes, how? :D

this is the goal, I just demonstrate what I mean, obviously the code below wont work:

```
var allPics = [
        {'name':'anti'    , 'path':'/images/anti.jpg'},
        {'name':'dark'    , 'path':'/images/dark.jpg'},
        {'name':'haik'    , 'path':'/images/haik.jpg'},
        {'name':'james'   , 'path':'/images/james.jpg'},
        {'name':'johanna' , 'path':'/images/johanna.jpg'},
        {'name':'timothy' , 'path':'/images/Timothy.jpg'}
        ]

+image(allPics)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use variables in an included file as well as `Mixins`.

`test.jade` includes `test_include.jade`

test_include.jade:

```
- var allPics  = [{'name':'anti'    , 'path':'/images/anti.jpg'},{'name':'dark'    , 'path':'/images/dark.jpg'},{'name':'haik'    , 'path':'/images/haik.jpg'},{'name':'james'   , 'path':'/images/james.jpg'},{'name':'johanna' , 'path':'/images/johanna.jpg'},{'name':'timothy' , 'path':'/images/Timothy.jpg'}]
mixin image(pics)
  each pic in pics
    .row
      .col-md-4
        img.img-responsive(src="#{pic.path}" alt="#{pic.name}")
block content
```

test.jade:

```
extends test_include
  block content
   +image(allPics)
```